# Getting An InputMismatchException On Line 16 From A 2D Array Input And I Can't Seem To Figure Out Why

Tags: java

I'm writing a program which takes a grid input and stores it as a 2d array. However, I keep on getting a InputMismatchException error and I can't seem to find out the cause of this. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Covid_Tracker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        char[][] A = new char[n][m];

        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < m; col++) {
                A[row][col]= in.next().charAt(0);;
            }
        }

        int p = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++){
            String firstName = in.next();
            int X = in.nextInt();
            int Y = in.nextInt();
        }

        int q = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i <= q; i++){
            String firstDirection = in.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Alice: infected");

    }
}
```

Here is the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

```
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)

at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)

at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)

at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)

at Assignment_1.main(Assignment_1.java:16)
```

An example input would be like:

5 4

X O O O O

O O O X O

O O O O O

O O O O O

1
Chris 4 1

3

Chris east

Chris north

Chris north

(This is the part I am still working on, so not in the code above) The program will then figure out where the person has traveled, and if they have gone through an area with Covid, the program will tell me if they are infected or not.

Comment: Glad to help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input should have no new lines.

I used the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Covid_Tracker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        char[][] A = new char[n][m];

        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < m; col++) {
                A[row][col]= in.next().charAt(0);;
            }
        }

        int p = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++){
            String firstName = in.next();
            int X = in.nextInt();
            int Y = in.nextInt();
        }

        int q = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i <= q; i++){
            String firstDirection = in.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Alice: infected");

    }
}
```

The input was

```
5 4
X O O O O
O O O X O
O O O O O
O O O O O
1 Chris 4 1
3
Chris east
Chris north
Chris north
```

And the output was

```
Alice:infected
```